# Copy parts of Windows registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm reinstalling Windows 7 tomorrow and to save myself some downloading and installing I wanted to copy my games. This won't just work, as some info is probably saved in the registry. This is why I was wondering if it's possible to copy parts of the registry.

Ideally I'm looking for a program that will automatically associate registry keys with programs. But just manual copying will be fine as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that some games, etc, also tie to the SID of the computer, so copying out the registry keys wont fully work.  Plus, the pathing, etc must all be the same.  @RedGrittyBrick below has the right information for doing exports, but it seems like a tricky venture to me.  I'd just reinstall the games, and restore my customization.

Comment: @zackrspv: Didn't know that :) Will probably just try it, and download if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regedit can be used to export selected nodes (and all subnodes) in the registry.

The resulting file can be run (Windows opens it with regedit) to add those entries to the registry.

Do backups first.